# Excel Custom Formatting Returning Unexpected Results

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am using the Excel custom number format `###0.0E-12` to format two numbers so that their exponent is both to the power of -12. One number (**1.23E-10**) gets formatted correctly, while Excel leaves the decimal part of the other number (**1.23E-09**) unchanged. What could be the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scientific formatting in Excel can be tricky some times. But try to use the following format. This should do the trick.

```
###########0.0E-0
```

Comment: Any reason why this would work?

Comment: It forces the number of digit placeholders to 12 and then applies the scientific format upon this. This is the only way - that I know of - that will "force" Excel to use the same exponent in the format without loosing the value of the underlying number so that the cell can be used in other calculations.

Comment: Brilliant. Works.